# Visual Studio SQL Data Compare ignores TimeStamp, even when I want it

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 I am trying to migrate the data from our type tables out to azure. I run the SQL Data Compare tool in Visual Studio, select the type tables, I see that the `Timestamp` column (which we've named `RercordVersion`) for the tables is selected. However, when I generate the script, that column is not included.

I checked Tools - Options - SQL Server Tools - Data Compare and the 'Include timestamp columns' option is checked. I unchecked then re-checked and tried again, but it still ignores the `Timestamp` column.

If I update the target database with the data, then re-run the compare, it wants to insert all the data a second time, since `RecordVersion` is now different.

Is there something I'm missing?

Is there another way I can replicate/sync/copy my type tables up to Azure?

Update: So I guess my main question is what is the best practice for keeping type tables in sync between on premises db and our azure databases?

Comment: Apparently Azure [automatically adds a required a `timestamp` column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx) and doesn't let you control it, and because a table [can only have one `timestamp` column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), you can't have yours.

Comment: It's interesting that it uses the same column name. Is there documentation that verifies this? That way I can go to the higher-ups with a documented reason.

Comment: `RercordVersion` is not listed as a reserved column name.